# Can anyone please explain how this Zener diode circuit works?

Tags: zener

I am learning how a Zener diode works.

Can anyone please explain me how to analyze this circuit (with equation if possible)?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't find your circuit very helpfull in understanding / explaining what a Zener diode does.
I would suggest you try this circuit instead and see if that helps you to understand:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbESju.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And forget about equations for a moment, and before you simulate this circuit just think about: what happens if the sinewave is -10 V, 0 V, + 10 V ???
No need to be precise, just think: will there be a current flowing or not, what will be the voltage across the zener diode ?

Real engineers first think: What will happen ? Only then simulate to confirm that !